# Current tab in IE 6 horizontal list navigation stretching to fill rest of div

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on getting my top nav to work in IE 6 - my site is
[located here](http://www.moreheadplanetarium.org/redesign/index.html).

The tabbed item is the "current" selected menu, and its width is stretching to fill the rest of the space... what should I do to fix this without fixing the width, but setting it in some way that it doesn't expand like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this in your CSS:

```
#nav li a span.top-nav-parent {
    background: url(images/nav/MPSC_tabs2.jpg) 100% 0;
    display: block;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-top: 13px;
}
```

Since you're using `SPAN` to display as a block element, set the display to `inline-block` instead.
Like so:

```
#nav li a span.top-nav-parent {
    background: url(images/nav/MPSC_tabs2.jpg) 100% 0;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-top: 13px;
}
```

This will now fix up your `.top-current` class from stealing the rest of the menu nav line.

Another thing is that it looks like you're including the stylesheet twice:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Remove one and you've just cut down a little on needless code.

Comment: Thanks, that works great!  I'm still learning CSS, so knowing about these small changes is really interesting to me.  

And the stylesheet is in there twice because of this program I'm using, CSSEdit, I'll just go in a remove the extras.  Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that was going on.